# How to use PySpark to extract data from an S3 Bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark

Using PySpark, I would like to extract data from a .csv file that is located in an S3 bucket. I successfully executed the program on the same file on my local CPU.

How can I successfully extract data from an S3 bucket using PySpark?

**S3 URL**

```
AIRPORT_DATA="s3a://udac-capstone/airports.csv"
```

**Code Use to Call Spark**

```
DL_AIRPORT_DATA = config_aws.AIRPORT_DATA

def create_spark_session():
    """ 
    Create spark entry point
    """
    spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.0") \
            .getOrCreate()
    return spark


def main():

    spark = create_spark_session()

    process_airports_data(spark, DL_AIRPORT_DATA, DL_OUTPUT_PATH)
```

**Code use to read in CSV**

```
def process_airports_data(spark, input_data, output_data):
    """
    Loads and processes the raw airport data using Spark. 
    Returns the data as a semi-schematized parquet file.
    """

    df = spark.read.option("header", True).csv(input_data)
```

**Traceback and error**:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/morgan/Documents/10_Udacity/data_eng_nano/usa-tourism-etl/main_cloud.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/morgan/Documents/10_Udacity/data_eng_nano/usa-tourism-etl/main_cloud.py", line 50, in main
    process_airports_data(spark, DL_AIRPORT_DATA, DL_OUTPUT_PATH)
  File "/Users/morgan/Documents/10_Udacity/data_eng_nano/usa-tourism-etl/etl.py", line 23, in process_airports_data
    df = spark.read.option("header", True).csv(input_data)
  File "/Users/morgan/opt/anaconda3/envs/udac_cap/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 737, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/Users/morgan/opt/anaconda3/envs/udac_cap/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Users/morgan/opt/anaconda3/envs/udac_cap/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/morgan/opt/anaconda3/envs/udac_cap/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.csv.
: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100M"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getLong(Configuration.java:1538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:796)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

}

Comment: i am getting a same error For input string: "100M"